# How to use asterisk (*) mark in the column header while exporting in CSV format in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a report on SSRS that will be exported into CSV format. For its first column I want asterisk(*) mark in the header. I have already tried everything but nothing seems to work.

How I want:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfLFU.png)

And this is how it appears after changing the DataElementOutput property to "output"-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzvVY.png)

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Show us what you've tried?

Comment: @JonTout I tried changing the "Name" property of detail element and it wont take special characters. Also, I tried changing the DataElementOutput property of header column to "Output" but then also it shows name of the value used in the textbox just below the header column(If we extract into csv format). I hope it clarifies.

Comment: That would have been my suggestion. I think that the only other way to achieve this is to export to Excel and then save that file as a CSV - which is a bit long winded. If there is a specific requirement for the report data to be CSV, then using SSIS would be a better way to go.